# What do people call spamming saves nowadays?

Tags: terminology

In the past, there were various derogatory terms for people who would abuse the ability to save the current state and keep retrying until non-deterministic decisions went in their way.

What is that called now?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Nowadays it is called [Save Scumming](https://allthetropes.orain.org/wiki/Save_Scumming), according to the trope wiki. This term comes from the Roguelike community, and different people may use different terms for that.

Answer (score 33):

I believe you are referring to [save scumming](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scumming).

I still do it on a fairly regular basis for the simple reason I don't have the time to redo large parts of a game!